# 3-Speed Kitchen Fan Wiring Problem

Tags: motor, fans

I goofed up and accidentally open the 3-speed switch controlling my kitchen fan. When I did that a bunch of metal connectors fell out and I can't figure out how they should be put back. The fan has 3 speeds the different metal things connect the different wires when pressed and as seen in picture 2 it has different notches.

The resistance between black-blue and white-black are the same and white-blue is double. Does anyone know how the wires should be connected to achieve the 3 different speeds? From there I can figure out how the metal strips should be placed.

The red and transparent cables are for the light and not a problem, the green and brown comes from the power plug, yellow and the 2 top blues go to the capacitor and white, black and blue goes to fan.

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Comment: Locate a service manual for the part and, just for the record, it's highly likely that your question is off-topic for this "design" site.

Comment: Switches with parts flying out are normally as repairable as electronics that the smoke has leaked out.

Comment: Get the make and model number of the fan in question. Then search for the manual online. List them here and provide a link to the manual.

Answer (score 1):

### Totally honest option:

1. Buy a new replacement switch of exactly the same model.
2. Install the new switch.

### Questionable but justifiable option:

3. Buy a new replacement switch of exactly the same model. Purchase from a vendor with a liberal return policy.
4. Carefully separate the casing. Do not let the parts fly all over the room.
5. Using the new switch as a model, replace the metal parts into your old switch in the exact matching positions.
6. Re-assemble the casing of the new switch. Test it. It must work as described in the user guide.
7. Re-assemble the casing of the old switch. Test it. It must work as described in the user guide.
8. Install the old switch.
9. Return the new switch for a refund as excess to requirements.

### Totally dishonest option:

1. Buy a new replacement switch of exactly the same model. Purchase from a vendor with a liberal return policy.
2. Install the new switch.
3. Return the old switch for a refund as defective.

### Result:

Not only do you have a working switch, but you now know what kind of person you are.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that that is not intended to be opened by the installer will be a puzzle to reassemble.

note the location of each wire disconnect them all.

take all the parts to a table.

using a magnifier inspect the parts closely for witness marks
that indicate where the parts touched and where they rubbed etc.

determine how the parts ewre located in the operating switch

plan a suequence of operations that ends with the switch correctly reassembled.

reassemble the switch

using your notes from the first step reconnect the wires.